# Stable differential structure

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

It is known that $\Bbb{R}^n$ has a unique smooth structure unless $n=4$, which leads to an interesting consequence: the exoticness of non-stantard smooth structures on $\Bbb{R}^4$ can be eliminated by a smooth deformation with the help of an additional dimension due to the uniqueness of smooth structures on $\Bbb{R}^5$. In other words, the different smooth structures on $\Bbb{R}^4$ are not **stably non-diffeomorphic**.

Do there exist manifolds that admit stably non-diffeomorphic differential structures? To describe it precisely, two differential structures $M_1$ and $M_2$ on the same manifold $M$ are said to be stably non-diffeomorphic if for any smooth manifold $N$, $M_1 \times N$ is not diffeomorphic to $M_2 \times N$.

I'd like to know the different answers (if there really are) when $M,N$ are required to be boundless/closed.

Comment: I see this question has been around for a while with no comments/answers. It might be a good fit for [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net).

Answer (score 1):

(Strictly speaking the answer is no since you allow $N = \varnothing$, so let me assume that $N$ should be non-empty.)

The following is not a complete answer since your notion of "stably non-diffeomorphic" is non-standard; usually one only allows products with $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, it may still be of interest to you.

Firstly, there is the product-structure theorem of Kirby-Siebenmann (Essay I.1 of [Foundational essays...](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirby/papers/Kirby%20and%20Siebenmann%20-%20Foundational%20Essays%20on%20Topological%20Manifolds,%20Smoothings%20and%20Triangulations%20-%20MR0645390.pdf)): it says that for a topological manifold $M$ taking the product with $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual smooth structure gives a bijection from the set of isotopy classes of smooth structures on $M$ to the set of isotopy classes of smooth structures on $M \times \mathbb{R}^n$, at least if $\dim(M) \geq 5$.

Secondly, a sufficient condition for two not-necessarily-homeomorphic closed manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ to *not* be stably non-diffeomorphic in your sense, is that there exists a homotopy equivalence $f \colon M_1 \to M_2$ such that $f^* TM_2 \oplus \epsilon^k \cong TM_1 \oplus \epsilon^k$ for some $k \geq 0$: there is a result of [Mazur](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-67/issue-4/Stable-equivalence-of-differentiable-manifolds/bams/1183524255.full) which says such an $f$ exists if and only if $M_1 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to $M_2 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \geq 0$. If you require all $N$'s to be closed, there is the following variant: if there exists a *simple* homotopy equivalence $f \colon M_1 \to M_2$ such that $f^* TM_2 \oplus \epsilon^k \cong TM_1 \oplus \epsilon^k$ for some $k \geq 0$, then  $M_1 \times S^n$ is diffeomorphic to $M_2 \times S^n$ for some $n \geq 0$. In fact, Mazur proved this with $D^n$ in place of $S^n$, but one can just take the double.

These two results are related as follows: by smoothing theory (Essay IV of [Foundational essays...](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirby/papers/Kirby%20and%20Siebenmann%20-%20Foundational%20Essays%20on%20Topological%20Manifolds,%20Smoothings%20and%20Triangulations%20-%20MR0645390.pdf)) the set of isotopy classes of smooth structures on $M$ with $\dim(M) \geq 5$ is in bijection with the set of homotopy classes of stable vector bundle structures on the stable tangent microbundle of $M$. Asking that two smooth structures $M_1$ and $M_2$ on a topological manifold $M$ have equivalent such stable vector bundle structures is asking whether for $f = \mathrm{id}_M$ it is true that $f^* TM_2 \oplus \epsilon^k \cong TM_1 \oplus \epsilon^k$ for some $k \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, so are there concrete stably non-diffeomorphic pairs?